# Should I be using a case statement or an if/else

Tags: shell, if-statement, unix, case

I am making a script in unix that will read a text file and each record has six fields separated by a pipe.
I don't know if I should use a case statement or an if/else statement.

- If the `$JOB` has a value of `P` then `NEW_NICE` should be set to `3`.
- If the `$JOB` has a value of `S` then `NEW_NICE` should be set to `6`.
- All other values of `$JOB` should set `NEW_NICE` to `7`.

I kinda wanna use a case statement because it would be simpler, but I also am not sure on how that would look.

Answer (score 2):

I won't tell you which one to use since it's a matter of preference. Either is fine. Let's do some comparison shopping so you can see them side by side.

(It's best to avoid all-uppercase variable names so as not to clash with any of the shell's built-in variables, which are always uppercase. I use `job` and `new_nice` below.)

Here's how the `case` statement would look. Use `*)` for the default case.

```
case "$job" in
    P) new_nice=3;;
    S) new_nice=6;;
    *) new_nice=7;;
esac
```

Here are two versions with `if` statements. In Bash you can use double brackets to avoid having to quote `"$job"`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $job == 'P' ]]; then
    new_nice=3
elif [[ $job == 'S' ]]; then
    new_nice=6
else
    new_nice=7
fi
```

If you're targeting plain sh then you'll have to use single brackets and quote `"$job"`.

You could also move the `else` case up top if that looks better. That could be nice if `7` is the default value and `3` and `6` are less common overrides.

```
#!/bin/sh

new_nice=7
if [ "$job" = 'P' ]; then
    new_nice=3
elif [ "$job" = 'S' ]; then
    new_nice=6
fi
```

Comment: I personally am in favor of the case statement since it's a bit easier for me to understand. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation

Comment: In the last example, better to use `=` instead of `==` to be compatible with the POSIX-standardized version of `[`. Personally, I suggest doing that with `[[` too to be in the habit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right, fixed.